# Groupby multiple columns with count in sql

Tags: sql, group-by

I need data from below output which will show  sales count per month with plan actual .

Original Data:

```
PlanMonth       ActualMth
Feb - 2018  Jan - 2018
Feb - 2018  Dec - 2017
Jan - 2018  Jan - 2018
Jan - 2018  Feb - 2018
Jan - 2018  Jan - 2018
Jan - 2018  Feb - 2018
Feb - 2018  Feb - 2018
Mar -2018       May - 2018
                Nov - 2018
                Feb - 2018
```

Expected Output:

```
Month       PlanCount ActualCount  
Feb - 2018    3         4
Jan - 2018    4         3
May -2018    Null       1
Nov - 2018   Null       1
Mar -2018    1         Null
```

**I tried below query **

Query:

```
Select ActualMonth, Count(ActualMonth), PlanMonth, Count(PlanMonth)
from table
group by ActualMonth, PlanMonth
```

It gives me below output which is wrong

```
PlanMonth  PlanCount ActualMonth ActualCount  
Jan-18       1            Jan-18        1   
Jan-18       2            Jan-18        2
Feb-2018     2            Feb - 2018    2
Feb-2018     2            Jan - 2018    2
```

Comment: Does the expected result really match the sample data? Why no Dec - 2017 in the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd `UNION ALL` the columns, and then `GROUP BY`:

```
select m, count(pm) planned, count(am) actual
from
(
  select PlanMonth m, 1 pm, null am from tab where PlanMonth is not null
  union all
  select ActualMth, null, 1 from tab where ActualMth is not null
) dt
group by m
```

(Will give 0 instead of NULL for non-existing months. You can do `nullif(count(pm), 0)` to get NULL - if desired.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your query is that you're trying to compute two different aggregations on the same aggregate field.

One option to solve this problem is linearizing your data into one single field on months and one type ('planned' or 'actual'), and then apply conditional aggregation using the `SUM` function to count how many times each date appears in the type partition.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT PlanMonth AS mth, 'planned' AS type FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ActualMth AS mth, 'actual' AS type FROM tab
)
SELECT mth, 
       SUM(type = 'planned') AS planned, 
       SUM(type = 'actual' ) AS actual
FROM cte
WHERE mth IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY mth
```

**Output**:

| month | planned | actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Feb - 2018 | 3 | 4 |
| Jan - 2018 | 4 | 3 |
| Mar - 2018 | 1 | 0 |
| Dec - 2017 | 0 | 1 |
| May - 2018 | 0 | 1 |
| Nov - 2018 | 0 | 1 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ePJp4v6o37yZfJBxCsJpwS/4).

Note: Don't use varchar type for date-like fields. Use instead the corresponding `DATE` field. Check answers in the thread [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/422047/should-i-use-date-or-varchar-in-storing-dates-in-mysql) to understand all drawbacks of having varchar instead of date.

Comment: This is not the same result as OP's expected. (But I'm not sure that OP's is as it should be...)